# valid iOS Distribution Cetificate - developer name change

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Here's how I've been led to this path.

I started on a macbook, with a standard developer account. Submitted a few applications. Then moved to an iMac, same developer account. Submitted a few applications.

Now, my developer account is a company account i.e, I got the name changed to my company name. However, now I cannot submit to the app store. I get `your account already has a valid iOS Distribution Certificate`

I cannot get past this hurdle!

I'll now try and explain which profiles and signing identities I have in my developer account.

### Certificates

Company name - iOS Distribution

My Old account name and/or my actual name - iOS Development

### App IDs

Application Name - Correct bundle identifier

### Provisioning Profiles

iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: App-Name - iOS Development

App Name - iOS Distribution - Active ( correct app id and correct certification for distribution )

All of these certificates are locally in my keychain.

However, I cannot get it to work. Some help would be greatly appreciated, I'm having an absolute nightmare.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Also possible that I'm not using xCode 5.0 for my solution. This is to do with switching the name of the developer account, now unable to code sign.

Comment: Accepted answer is always not right, answer accepted because it was worked for the questioner. see other answers too

Comment: @AshishKakkad The problem is, a lot of the solutions include putting my previous submissions at risk. I cannot afford any down time. So I don't want to take a risk and try any old solution when I could just be digging a deeper hole. I was hoping someone could look at my questions and give me a solution based on what I've said. Which will avoid deleting anything I don't need to delete.

Comment: Other user will watch and reply. Don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate is just used to prove that you are the person who (signed and) submitted the app.

Apple re-signs your app with their credentials before it appears on the store.  You can be assured that revoking a certificate won't invalidate any previous submissions for this reason.

The issue right now is that Xcode and/or keychain are likely affected by (or using) conflicted (or old) details, and Xcode doesn't recognize that something has changed, or cannot replace the old data with the current data.

You should revoke your certificate(s), delete them from Xcode and keychain, then let Xcode generate a new one.

Otherwise, those old keys will linger in Xcode and keychain and be a point of confusion, both now, and down the road.

*I realize it seems like an ominous thing to do, but if there were dire consequences, Apple would clearly be warning you, instead of letting you simply revoke and be reissued a new certificate.*

Answer (score 1):

Solution in my case.

I deleted all old certificates/keys, revoked my distribution profile from the members centre ( so I didn't have any ) Then proceeded to xCode>Accounts>View Info> + > distribution profile and it generated me a new one.

This has now allowed me to submit via the app store and remove the very vague error.

Comment: @AshishKakkad haha thank you, It's such a vague error and a lot at stake. They should really spend a bit more time on their error handling.